# Why do I get a permission error installing Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM?

Tags: ruby

I need to install a newer version of Ruby than 1.8.7.

I already managed to install Homebrew and RVM, but this is what happens when I try to install Ruby.

```
aldaman:~ Alex$ rvm install 1.9.3
mkdir: /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p429: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p429: Permission denied
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p429.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Already up-to-date.
mkdir: /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p429: Permission denied
tee: /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p429/1370998530_package_install_openssl.log: No such file or directory
tee: /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p429/1370998530_package_install_openssl.log: No such file or directory
Installing required packages: openssl.............................
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install openssl',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p429/1370998530_package_install_openssl.log
```

I have no idea how to fix it. Does someone know how?

Comment: While you *can* install RVM "multi-user", it's generally better to do it for "single-user", and, is actually recommended: `Single-User installations (recommended) - For an isolated install within a user's $HOME, not for root.`. See https://rvm.io/rvm/install/, especially the section following "Installation explained" for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running with `sudo`:

```
sudo rvm install 1.9.3
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you installed rvm in 'Multi-user' mode aka 'system wide installation'.

You should follow the instruction and add your user to 'rvm' group and reopen a session. Once this is done you will be able to install any rubies directly `rvmsudo rvm install 1.9.3`

As often we should be careful on when to use a root account or a sudo invocation. As told in the rvm installation guide there no case where to use `sudo` only case with `rvmsudo`.